# How to push and pop a stack of doubles using structures and pointers

Tags: c++, struct, stack, lifo

There's this assignment that requires me to make items of a specific structure and stack an unlimited number of them. I should also be able to pop the item at the top of the list. I've been able to stack them but when I attempt to pop my program freezes.

The rules for the pop function are as  follows:
"Finds the item at the top of the stack, saves its value to a variable, makes its next item the new stack top. uses the delete operator to return its memory back to the operating system, decrements stack size by 1, and returns its saved value.  If the stack is empty, it returns the constant variable HUGE_VAL which is defined in the  header file. It's critical that you get the value of the popped item before you delete it; don't access the value of an already-deleted item."

I'm also having an issue with HUGE_VAL, it's advising me that it is undefined even though it is a constant from one of the imports. Below is my code:

Please advise me as to what I might be doing wrong

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;



struct Item{
   double value; // The actual value of the item
   Item* next;   // A pointer to the item beneath
};

struct Stack {
   Item* top; // A pointer to the item at the top
   int size;  // How many items are in the stack? 0 if the stack is empty
};

void push(Stack* stack, double num) {
    Item* item = new Item; 
    item->value = num;
    item->next = nullptr;

    if(stack->top){
        item->next= stack->top;
    }

    stack->top = item;
    stack->size++;
}


double pop(Stack* stack){
    
    Item *current = stack->top;  //identifying the value at the top of the stack
    double value;  //variable to store the value of the Item to be popped
    while(current)
    if(current == stack->top){
        current->value = value;
         stack->top = current->next;
                
    }else{
        return HUGE_VAL;
    }
    stack->size--;
   delete current; 
   
    return 0;
}

void printStack(const Stack* stack){
    Item* item = stack->top;
    while(item){
        cout<< item->value <<endl;
        item = item->next;
    }

}

int main(){
   Stack stack ={nullptr, 0};

   push(&stack, 12 );
   push(&stack, 23 );
   push(&stack, 11.0 );
   printStack(&stack);
   pop(&stack);
   printStack(&stack);



}
```

Comment: Just realized that I didn't open and close my while loop so now my current issue is resolved lol

Comment: Issue remaining now is that there seems to be no identification of an empty stack condition so HUGE_VAL never seems to be returned.

Comment: Why do you even need a loop for popping?..

Comment: See my implementation in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `pop` function (properly formatted):

```
double pop(Stack* stack){
    Item *current = stack->top;  //identifying the value at the top of the stack
    double value;  //variable to store the value of the Item to be popped
    while (current)
        if (current == stack->top) {
            current->value = value;
            stack->top = current->next;
        }
        else {
            return HUGE_VAL;
        }
    stack->size--;
    delete current; 
   
    return 0;
}
```

if your stack is not empty, the `current != nullptr`. You never change it's value and never exit the loop. Here is the code that works on non empty stack:

```
    while (true) // current is always != nullptr
        if (true) { // (current == stack->top) is always true
            current->value = value;
            stack->top = current->next;
            // current is never changed
        }
```

You probably meant:

```
double pop(Stack* stack){
    Item *current = stack->top;
    if (current) {
        double value = current->value;
        stack->top = current->next;
        stack->size--;
        delete current;
        return value; 
    }
    return HUGE_VAL;
}
```

Comment: assuming that last bit of code was the only thing required for implementation then it's doing just about the same thing. My question though- is HUGE_VAL supposed to return an actual value or simply exit the program?

Comment: @ChadrickHollingsworth, that is up to you, but the most idiomatic way is to throw an exception. That should be the responsibility of the client's code to check the stack size before popping.